# Get JSON data from URL & display it using innerHTML - how?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following code that grabs all the data from an array and then displays it in a certain div within an HTML document.  Right now the data is embedded into the code, yet I need to grab this same data from a URL.  As you can see I already started the XHR request & tested it's retrieval successfully.  I'm just not sure once the data is grabbed from the URL how to display it within the HTML similarly as it works now?

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com', true);
xhr.send(null);

// LOAD AND DISPLAY LOCATION DATA
window.onload=function(){
var data = [ 
 {"id":1271832,"segment_id":3345,"latitude":37.7029,"longitude":-121.9335,"name":"Verve","address_1":"7886 Dublin Blvd","phone_number":"555-324-5678","postal_code":"94568","postal_code_id":"7168","metro":"San Francisco-Oakland-San Jose CA","city":"Dublin","region":"CA","country":"US","m":4934,"km":4.9,"miles":3.07},
 {"id":1271836,"segment_id":3345,"latitude":37.6958,"longitude":-121.9255,"name":"Verve","address_1":"1 Stoneridge Mall Space","phone_number":"555-324-5678","postal_code":"94588","postal_code_id":"7169","metro":"San Francisco-Oakland-San Jose CA","city":"Pleasanton","region":"CA","country":"US","m":5045,"km":5,"miles":3.14},
 {"id":1271831,"segment_id":3345,"latitude":37.6931,"longitude":-121.9262,"name":"Verve","address_1":"1120 Stoneridge Mall Drive","phone_number":"555-324-5678","postal_code":"94566","postal_code_id":"7167","metro":"San Francisco-Oakland-San Jose CA","city":"Pleasanton","region":"CA","country":"US","m":5325,"km":5.3,"miles":3.31},
 {"id":1271827,"segment_id":3345,"latitude":37.6999,"longitude":-121.7452,"name":"Verve","address_1":"4408 Las Positas Rd","phone_number":"555-324-5678","postal_code":"94551","postal_code_id":"7138","metro":"San Francisco-Oakland-San Jose CA","city":"Livermore","region":"CA","country":"US","m":13375,"km":13.4,"miles":8.31},
 {"id":1271826,"segment_id":3345,"latitude":37.6966,"longitude":-122.0771,"name":"Verve","address_1":"3450 Village Dr","phone_number":"555-324-5678","postal_code":"94546","postal_code_id":"7133","metro":"San Francisco-Oakland-San Jose CA","city":"Castro Valley","region":"CA","country":"US","m":16796,"km":16.8,"miles":10.44},
 {"id":1271838,"segment_id":3345,"latitude":37.8948,"longitude":-122.0591,"name":"Verve","address_1":"1295 S Main St","phone_number":"555-324-5678","postal_code":"94596","postal_code_id":"7292","metro":"San Francisco-Oakland-San Jose CA","city":"Walnut Creek","region":"CA","country":"US","m":23294,"km":23.3,"miles":14.48},
 {"id":1271833,"segment_id":3345,"latitude":37.7114,"longitude":-122.1638,"name":"Verve","address_1":"1285 Marina Boulevard","phone_number":"555-324-5678","postal_code":"94577","postal_code_id":"7170","metro":"San Francisco-Oakland-San Jose CA","city":"San Leandro","region":"CA","country":"US","m":24055,"km":24.1,"miles":14.95},
 {"id":1271819,"segment_id":3345,"latitude":37.9499,"longitude":-121.9603,"name":"Verve","address_1":"5412 Ygnacio Valley Rd","phone_number":"555-324-5678","postal_code":"94521","postal_code_id":"7254","metro":"San Francisco-Oakland-San Jose CA","city":"Concord","region":"CA","country":"US","m":24926,"km":24.9,"miles":15.49},
 {"id":1271817,"segment_id":3345,"latitude":37.9435,"longitude":-121.7376,"name":"Verve","address_1":"2520 Sand Creek Rd","phone_number":"555-324-5678","postal_code":"94513","postal_code_id":"7248","metro":"San Francisco-Oakland-San Jose CA","city":"Brentwood","region":"CA","country":"US","m":27090,"km":27.1,"miles":16.84},
 {"id":1271820,"segment_id":3345,"latitude":37.9452,"longitude":-122.0627,"name":"Verve","address_1":"157 Crescent Plaza","phone_number":"555-324-5678","postal_code":"94523","postal_code_id":"7256","metro":"San Francisco-Oakland-San Jose CA","city":"Pleasant Hill","region":"CA","country":"US","m":28030,"km":28,"miles":17.42} 
  ];

data.forEach(function (item) {
    pios(item)
})

function pios(item) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.id = item.id;
    p.innerHTML = item.address_1 + '<br>' + item.city + item.region + item.postal_code;
    document.getElementById('locations').appendChild(p)
}
}
```

```html
<div id="locations"></div>
```

Comment: This out this example: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_http.asp. It's the same with what you want to do.

Comment: Are you trying to load JSON data from **another** server? Your web page and the JSON data *must* come from the same URL (which implies that your AJAX url should just be of the form "path/to/api" and not need the "http://" or the domain name) unless the other server allows your server to access the data via CORS headers. This also means that your html page can't be loaded from the hard disk (since local storage has no domain name) but must be served by a web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the onreadystatechange to your xhr:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            pios(item);
        });
    }
}
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.send();
```

This includes the full methods you provided and linked it into the onload.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            data.forEach(function (item) {
                pios(item);
            });
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com', true);
    xhr.send();
};

function pios(item) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.id = item.id;
    p.innerHTML = item.address_1 + '<br>' + item.city + item.region + item.postal_code;
    document.getElementById('locations').appendChild(p)
}
```

Comment: Could you show a full example?  I tried adding your code after my var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); but my locations no longer display on the page.  I'm a newbie; really appreciate the help!

Comment: Just added - hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you!  I grabbed all the code from you 2nd grey block though when I run it the console throws, "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function," on line 9.  THough maybe I need to use more then just the 2nd code block you have there?

Comment: Here's a working JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/4my8ohsz/) showing how all the code can work together. Since I don't have access to your datasource, I used a different endpoint (github), but it shows in the comments how to put your code back in.  I'd also make sure you're not seeing security errors due to cross-site origin limitation (Access-Control-Allow-Origin header not configured properly on the endpoint)

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out and wanted to share.  Thanks for the help!

***Don't forget to change http://example.com with the URL to your JSON data.

```js
function getData(callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            callback(data);
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com', true);
    xhr.send();
}

function renderData(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var html = data.pois.slice(0,3).reduce(function (frag, item) {
        frag.appendChild(pios(item));
        return frag;
    }, document.createDocumentFragment());
    document.getElementById('locations').appendChild(html);
}

function pios(item) {
    var p = document.createElement('pre');
    p.id = item.id;
    p.textContent = item.address_1 + '\n' + item.city + ' ' + item.region + ' ' + item.postal_code;
    return p;
}

getData(renderData);
```

```html
<div id="locations"></div>
```